# Todo list or bug tracking solution in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to develop a tool to track my todo list. I would like to start with an open-source **asp.net MVC solution**. To gain time, it may be helpful for me to start with an existing solution and adjust it to my specific needs.

So I searched the web (codeplex, ...) and don't find usable solution to start with. Maybe someone here can inform me some existing ASP.NET MVC solution?

Something like a todo list or a bug tracking solution.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!
[Tool written with Asp.Net and Backbone.js](https://github.com/kalpers/Todo-App--Backbone.js-and-ASP.Net-MVC)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very good starting point for my todo list! You saved my day :)